# How can I remap the shortcut keys for scroll down/up in gnome terminal

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

According the [gnome-terminal usage](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/3.6/gnome-terminal-usage.html.en#gnome-terminal-contents):

> You can also scroll up or down one line at a time by pressing Control+Shift+Up or Control+Shift+Down.

In this document shows: <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> / <kbd>Down</kbd> can **scroll up** or **scroll down** the `gnome-terminal` one line. And, yes, they can!

Now, I want to re-map these two shortcut keys, like: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>K</kbd> (Vimer habit).

### My understanding

Here some signal must be triggered after press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> | Down.

The question is, **what signal is triggered?**

---

Here are some questions:

- `0x115` is [the signal of windows scrolling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). what about Linux?
- Can the scrolling be executed by command in gnome-terminal? (Some command inputted and gnome-terminal scrolling up/down)

I've download the source code of Gnome-Terminal, and tried to find the answer. But my C is terrible...

---

By the way, my Linux is Ubuntu 13.10, and `gnome-terminal` is 3.6:

```
$ gnome-terminal --version
GNOME Terminal 3.6.1
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [OPTIONAL]

I'm a vimer too and I feel uncomfortable with the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> position so I remapped the Window's <kbd>Meta</kbd> to be an additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  **NOTE:** you'll need `xmodmap`.

```
remove Control = Control_L Control_R
remove mod4 = Super_L Super_R
add Control = Control_L Super_L
```

#### [STEPS]

To remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> in `Konsole` follow these steps:

1. Go to *Settings* -> *Configure Current Profile* -> *Input*
2. Edit the Linux Console key binding
3. Add a new key binding to scroll down a line at a time: <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -> ScrollLineDown
4. Add a new key binding to scroll up a line at a time: <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -> ScrollLineUp

#### Some screenshots

[image]

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:** Now you'll be able to scroll up and scroll down a line at a time using the configured shortcuts.

#### EDIT #1

<kbd>Alt</kbd> does work!! Just change <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd> in the bindings.

Comment: Where is the documentation for the list of keywords that `ScrollLineDown` and `ScrollLineUp` come from?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you're looking for is here, titled: [Keyboard shortcuts](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/3.8/adv-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en). Specifically these:

[image: ss #!]

**NOTE:** You can't override this keyboard shortcut through `gnome-terminal`! If you could it would show up in this menu:

#### To change a keyboard shortcut:

1. Select Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Shortcuts.
2. Select the shortcut that you wish to edit by clicking on it.
3. Once the shortcut is selected, click on the shortcut key combination to edit it.
4. Type in your desired shortcut key combination as you would enter it to use it. The keys that you can use include Alt, Alt Gr, Ctrl, Shift, number and letter keys.

   **NOTE:** Mnemonic key combinations, such as Alt+F will not work. If you accidentally set one of these key combinations as a shortcut, you may need to reset it before you can change it to something else.
5. Once you have entered your new shortcut, it will automatically be saved and you should see it in the list next to the corresponding action.

**NOTE:** To disable a shortcut, edit it and press the Backspace instead of the new shortcut.

#### Some shortcuts cannot be overridden!

If you notice in the screenshot above (a bit hard to see) it states that:

> There are also some shortcuts that cannot be edited

These would include the scrolling up/down, so it would seem there isn't a way to do this directly through `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: This shortcut is not the "regular" terminal shortcut. Can you found any settings for `scroll one line` in `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Shortcuts`? No!!! Because I've checked that place long long time ago!

Comment: @Marslo - Sorry I think you misunderstood what I said. The screenshot shows that you cannot edit these. I've expanded my A to make that more obvious. The same is also mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/247539/how-can-i-change-the-keyboard-shortcuts-for-single-line-scrolling-in-the-termina

Comment: @Marslo - yes until you asked this Q I would've guessed that this is modifiable. Makes no sense why it wouldn't be. I would take a look in `dconf-editor`. Things are sometimes doable there when the regular GUIs don't expose it.

Comment: @Marslo - yes I know, I added them to make that line in the output more obvious. Sorry about that. I thought the line in the screenshot was obvious, but based on your reaction I'm guessing it wasn't 8-)

Comment: Hi @slm, actually, I'm very thanks for your A. I've also checked the `dconf-editor`, but nothing found. Hope you can surprise me! :)

Comment: In windows, I can remap the shortcuts by [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). In this way, I needn't modified any settings, just remap `alt+j => ctrl+shift+up`. And, also I tried `xbindkeys`, I found this tools needs command, for example, I can remap `ctrl+j`==>`gnome-terminal`. That means, terminal would be startup while I press `ctrl+j`

Comment: The `xmodmap` method or `xbindkeys` are the 2 ways I would go about it outside of gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

#### A solution using autokey

You can use [autokey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) to change shortcuts for certain windows. Autokey allows you to filter window titles via regular expression.

1) Just install autokey and create a new script.

2) Paste the following code into the script window and change it according to your needs.:

```
# This code will scroll the terminal three lines up, when triggered.

import time

keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<shift>+<up>")
time.sleep(0.01)
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<shift>+<up>")
time.sleep(0.01)
keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<shift>+<up>")
time.sleep(0.01)
```

2) Then tell autokey to assign the script to a "Hotkey" of your choice.

3) At last set the the regular expression for "Window Filter" to something like this `^Terminal$`, depending on the title of your terminal windows. You may adjust your regular expression in order to match your specific window title. [This site](https://regex101.com/) is very helpful, when fiddling around with regular expressions.

4) Do the same for scrolling down.