# How can KDE Konsole be prevented from trapping the Ctrl/Alt/Shift + Cursor keys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, konsole, cursor

I need to use some Alt and Shift cursor combinations in `emacs` and the KDE Konsole is interfering with them. It switches the tabs instead. How can I disable that behaviour?

It is hard to tell whether it is something to configure in the necessary terminal itself or it is something controlled at the level of the GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can partly be done in the  `Settings->Configure Shortcuts` menu in `Konsole`.

[image: Configure Shortcut dialog in Konsole]

As can be seen from the image the Shift Right key was for navigating to the next tab, and it has been disabled.

The Alt key may require different dialogs and there is a related question - [How can I remap the shortcut keys for scroll down/up in gnome terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110991/how-can-i-remap-the-shortcut-keys-for-scroll-down-up-in-gnome-terminal) which also gives some insight into the process